# Looking to have a script to add a column daily. In cell #1 put current date, in all the other cells below, add a dropdown from a set of choices

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script already for adding a column and dating it appropriately, however I cannot figure out how to get formatting and dropdown to then be added to the new column after it has been added.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1br0RcNQaVL_hMuf5SPcrDH0HDjJY5BXO9QwZMG1jK4g/edit#gid=493580579

I have this script in place to add new column and date it.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name');
sheet.insertColumnAfter(3);
sheet.getRange("D1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy');
sheet.setColumnWidth(4,196)
}
```

Comment: [DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add dropdown with Apps Script, you can use the `DataValidationBuilder` class. I added a few lines to the sample script you shared. Just make sure to change the choices you want in the dropdown and also adjust the range where you will add the dropdown, in my sample I'm adding it to range `D2:D10`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name');
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(3);
  sheet.getRange("D1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy');
  sheet.setColumnWidth(4,196)
  
  sheet.getRange('D2:D10').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(['Option 1', 'Option 2'], true)
  .build());
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I see that you have merged cells, I think it would be easier to copy the column, insert a new one and paste content including the format from the previous column. I used the following script:

```
function copyPasteColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name');

  sheet.insertColumnsBefore(4, 1);
  sheet.getRange('E:E').copyTo(sheet.getRange('D:D'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  sheet.getRange('D:D').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("D1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy');
  sheet.setColumnWidth(4,196);
}
```

## References:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: That definitely worked for the question I asked!

However, I guess I didn't ask what I wanted to appropriately. 

I have a column adding to Column D each day, Dating it appropriately, however under that, I am wanting the same formatting that is now in Column E to autopop into Column D. 

The idea behind the spreadsheet is to make sure I am touching a client for 10 days in a row. So I have Date Assigned in Column A, Name in Column B, Running count of how many touches they currently have in Column C. The D on is each date. I have formatting set up  that has red/green for touched/not touch.

Comment: As well as a drop down that has Call, Text, Email, Text with Video, and Email with Video all with specific conditional formatting for color coordination.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet? I'm not able to access to the one you shared in your question.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1br0RcNQaVL_hMuf5SPcrDH0HDjJY5BXO9QwZMG1jK4g/edit?usp=sharing

I changed the restrictions. Sorry I thought I already had.

Comment: @JayMcRae I made an update to my answer, I tried the script and it added the dropdown menu to the new column and also the same format from the previous column, let me know if that works well.

Comment: @JayMcRae did the update work for you? Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: YES!!! It worked wonderfully! Thank you!!!! That is EXACTLY what I was wanting !